# Ways to get content in a div thats is on a included page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Kinda hard to name this topic, right using pretty much anything to do with HTML and PHP how can I get content in a div that is on a included page.

Let me try make some sense of this:

header.php has the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="primary">
        <div class="title">Stats</div>
        <p>Primary Sidebar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="title">Content</div>
        <p>Main content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="secondary">
        <div class="title">Other</div>
        <p>Secondary Sidebar</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#primary {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    height: 600px;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 474px;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#secondary {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    height: 600px;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
}
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/MgjqK/2/)

So that's the page that is going to be included on other pages. It has the layout (mainly side menus). Now is there any way I can get content from pages that includes `header.php` in the div `content`.

**E.G of what the content could be:** A simple HTML table with data.

Any other ways to do this would be great to know as well, Because I already have pages made with content ready to go into that div I would like it to stay the way I have it but if its not possible or just plain up stupid I can change it.

I hope that made some kind of sense, Im finding this rather hard to explain. I have looked around and cant find what I need.

**UPDATE**
Heres a pic to explain better.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Do you know how to use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in PHP?

Comment: This is a pretty trivial operation - Are you looking for a PHP or JavaScript solution?

Comment: @Sébastien Not following you on that one.. Explain, header.php is not the file that includes other pages. Other pages include header.php. So unless im missing something its not possible using include that way round?

Comment: @adamb Any tbh, both would be good but whatever way is "best" I guess.

Comment: I want to see if I understand you. You want the content that is included under each of these respected divs. For example: You want all the content from STATS and want a script that pulls that if header.php is included on that page?

Comment: @TimAldridge You have a page called `info.php` on that page is just words e.g:"blah blah blah". Also on the page you include `header.php` (the code above, its the template) How can the content on `info.php` be placed into the div `content` that is on `header.php`

Comment: On `info.php` do you really have 'just words e.g:"blah blah blah"' or do you **also** have `header.php` included in `info.php`?

Comment: @Sébastien I have made an update to my question using my amazing paint skills. See if you can get it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Storing the outputs in a variable and using later.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm not simplifying too much:

```
//index.php    
$stats = 'Some text here';
include('header.php');
```

Then:

```
//header.php
<div id="container">
    <div id="primary">
        <div class="title">Stats</div>
        <p><?php echo $stats; ?></p>
```

Comment: Its not just going to be a string. Its going to be tables, text, PHP and so on.

Comment: OK, same thing.  Maybe more info if that's not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a decent amount of flexibility with your template.

Try creating separate files for the primary and secondary DIV's, for example:

```
//primary-sidebar.php
<div id="container">
    <div id="primary">
        <div class="title">Stats</div>
        <p>Primary Sidebar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">


//secondary-sidebar.php
 </div>
    <div id="secondary">
        <div class="title">Other</div>
        <p>Secondary Sidebar</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then for each page the code would look like this (we'll start with index.php)

```
//index.php
include 'primary-sidebar.php';

<div class="title">Content</div>
<p>Main content</p>

include 'secondary-sidebar.php';
```

Comment: Ah you understand what I mean but I was trying to avoid putting a div on every page. Just want the content in the div thats on `header.php`